# How do I perform a LLMNR query?

Tags: windows, reverse-dns

I wish to perform a LLMNR query explicitly.  My current environment includes DNS servers so the ping (ping -a specifically) is doing DNS queries to resolve the name.  I can disable my DNS in my network configuration, but that isn't an ideal solution.

How do I perform a LLMNR query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming PowerShell is available, use [`Resolve-DnsName -LlmnrOnly -Name <host>`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781(v=wps.630).aspx)

From the linked TechNet page:

> -LlmnrOnly
>   Resolves this query using only the LLMNR protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Can you remove the appended DNS Suffix from your local config?

- Go to your ethernet connection.
- Click Properties.
- Double click
  Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)
- Click Advanced.
- Click the DNS
  tab. Remove whatever the suffix is.